# How to Restrict a SAML 302 Redirect to an IFRAME?

Tags: http, iframe, redirect, single-sign-on, saml

Is it possible to load content within an IFRAME that subsequently returns a 302 redirect, without having it redirect the entire browser window to the destination? I.e. limit the redirect to the IFRAME itself? If so, how?

EDIT1: To restate... i have an IFRAME, the source of which is a self-posting FORM. The action returns a 302 to somewhere else. When that happens, the entire page redirects. What i want is to have ONLY the IFRAME redirect, leaving the surrounding page alone.

EDIT2: To clarify further, this is an SSO SAML implementation. The IFRAME content should contain the newly signed-into application. The SSO is working correctly but the entire browser page redirects into the application, losing the containing page. The SAML aspect may not change the diagnosis that the application is "frame-busting," but it may trigger some other ideas.

Comment: Huh? What you want already is the standard behaviour. Or do you mean something else? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Pekka - I think i was unclear. Restated the problem.

Comment: that should absolutely not happen. Can you post an on-line example?

Comment: @Pekka - unfortunately no, i can't post an example. Perhaps i'm misreading what's happening; you and @Martin seem to agree that what i describe isn't possible so i'll see if i can locate more information from the owner of the page i'm IFRAME-ing, in which case i'll post more here. Thanks.

Comment: Added info on SAML SSO to question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's impossible **not** to limit a 302 redirect to the iframe itself.
An HTTP redirect occuring inside an iframe will never affect the containing page. What you're asking for is already the only behaviour you will see.

There's probably a frame busting script on the redirect target page. It's difficult to prevent an iframe from breaking out, but [there are tricks](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/) to deal with that too.

Comment: @Martin - what i'm seeing is the entire page redirecting, when i want only the IFRAME content to redirect.

Comment: i'll keep digging and try to get more info from the owner of the redirecting page. Maybe there *is* something else going on. I'll post more info if i get any. Thanks.

Comment: In case of HTML5, there is `sandbox` attribute for `iframe` tag. Looks like working.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are dealing with a JavaScript-based "Frame buster" on the redirection target page's end. You would have to switch that off, or have it switched off.

Comment: @Pekka - that's possible. I have added info explaining that this is a SAML SSO situation. I will see if i can find out if the SSO target app is frame-busting.

Comment: @bill turn off JavaScript (e.g. using the Web Developer Toolbar in Firefox) and see whether the behaviour persists. It is also possible to set a `target='_top'` property in a form, which will escape the iframe without JavaScript.

Comment: +1 - yes, frame-busting was present on the loaded page. Accepting @Martin's answer since it was first.